# Docker compose and nginx.php.mysql

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

After working on docker-compose file and after run command (On Windows  10)

```
docker-compose up -d
```

i got he next error once i visiting

> http://localhost:8088/

[image: The Result]

my docker compose file is

```
version: "3"

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

DockerFile is

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

nginx/default.conf is (which is i think the problem in because when i empty it i got not found page)

```
 server{
     listen 80;
     index index.php index.html;
     server_name: localhost;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
     root /var/www/public;
 
     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }
 
     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass php:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fascgi_path_info;
    } }
```

after empty this file

```
server{
    # listen 80;
    # index index.php index.html;
    # server_name: localhost;
    # error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    # access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # root /var/www/public;

    # location / {
    #     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    # }

    # location ~ \.php$ {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    #     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #     fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    #     fastcgi_index index.php;
    #     include fastcgi_params;
    #     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fascgi_path_info;
    # }
}
```

and rebuild and up the composer i got next screen
[image]

Comment: carefully check your container logs.  since you told nginx to log to files you'll also need to check those.

Comment: where is the location of those file in windows 10